# Django - Show foreign key value instead of object in the drop down form

Tags: django

I am trying to implement a form that uses two models connected through a foreign key. Below is my current setup:

**Primary Model:**

```
class Firstlist(models.Model):
      TBlname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
   return self.name
```

**Second Model:**

```
class SecondList(models.Model):
   Status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Tblnameref = models.ForeignKey(Firstlist)

def __str__(self):
return self.name
```

**Form:**

```
class MainForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = SecondList
    fields = ('Tblnameref','Status')

  def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(SecondList,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['Tblnameref'].empty_label = '-- Select --'
```

**Template:**

```
<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
{{form.Tblnameref}}
<button>Validate</button>
{{form.Status}}
<button>Validate</button>
</form>
```

However when I test this, the values in drop down show up as "Tblnameref object (1)" instead of the actual value.

Can someone please advise how to fix this so that the drop down shows actual value than the object. Thank you for the help

Comment: please share your views.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the following code

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.name
```

there should be a field `name` in your model but it seems you don't have it.

Change the `__str__` method in your Firstlist model.

```
class Firstlist(models.Model):
      TBlname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
   return self.TBLname
```

The `__str__` function is used to add a string representation of a model's object, here it will show the value of `TBLname`, you can change it as per your requirement.

Do the same for second model also as it seems it doesn't have a `name` field either, try using a field already present in the model.

See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#other-model-instance-methods) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much.. This is helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is very normal, Your model the field Tblnameref of the model SecondList, stores only "id"s of Firstlist (primary key). so to have values instead, you must do a query to Firstlist inorder to get the id '1'

```
Firstlist.objects.get(id__exact="yourvariable_Tblnameref").TBlname
```